# docker prometheus not able to access docker kafka_exporter

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, prometheus

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  kafka_exporter:
    image: danielqsj/kafka-exporter
    command: --kafka.server=xx.xx.xx.xx:9092 --kafka.server=xx.xx.xx.xx:9092
    ports:
      - 9308:9308
    links:
      - prometheus
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    ports:
    - 9090:9090
    volumes:
    - ./mount/prometheus:/etc/prometheus
    command: --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

Above is my `docker-compose.yml` file.
I am able to spin up both the images.

However, I am not able to access `localhost:9308` (**kafka_Exporter**) from `localhost:9090` (prometheus)

Do I need to link/network images?

Comment: When you say not able to access localhost:9308 (kafka_Exporter) from localhost:9090 (prometheus), You mean through Browser or internally from one container to another..?

Comment: Through the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be container_name:port

```
kafka_exporter:9308
```